Copy text extracted from multiple lines
Say, I have the following text:
Mr John Smith (email: john.smith@example.com),42
Mrs Ann Brown (email: annie@example.com),23
Dr Hu Zhang (email: zhang@example.com),30

(the real text has many more lines)
I need to copy all the emails, preferably one per line.
How can I do this in Vim using only its standard features?

What does "copy" mean? How do you want the copied text to look (newline separated, all on one line, etc.)? How are you using it? Do you actually need to "copy" them or is "copying" the first thing you thought of when faced with the problem at hand?

I need to copy them to use in some other place, so ideally have them stored in a register, ideally one email on a line

But somehow modifying the text is also ok, since I can always copy the result and then undo the modification with u

I would do:
:%s/.*(email: \(.*\)).*/\1/

This substitution would keep only the email address in each of the lines.
You could then copy them all:
:%y

And then undo the changes:
u


Funnily enough, I would do it the other way around and first copy the lines to their new location (or maybe even a scratch buffer), then run :s. I guess it would keep the original buffer's undo history; although I usually don't care about this level of sophistication.

An alternate approach, though Vivian’s is great:

Clear a register: qaq
Yank all the emails to that register: :global/email/normal! 0f:l"Ayt)

This won’t put newlines between the emails. A cleverer command (or a sub-replace-special that calls setreg or something like that) could solve that problem.

If you want to paste the emails outside vim you can do: :let @+=@a this will copy the content of a register to the clipboard.  I do not recomment using right away the clipboard register because i think it does not append each copy (but I am not sure)
